# jQuery hover animation efficiency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got my hover working - but i'm interested in trying to make it more efficient as it does seems to 'lag' when it's finding the .`overlay` div. I also had the issue where I was animating all `.overlay` divs on a page, which I consider to be quite a noob mistake.

Anyway, let's learn how to make the below better!

**jQuery**:

```
// get aside feature
var aside_feature = $('aside .feature');

// on hover, fade it in
$( aside_feature ).hover(function() {
    // get the overlay div
    var feature_overlay = $(this).find('.overlay');
    $(feature_overlay).stop().fadeIn();
// on hover out, fade it out
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.overlay').stop().fadeOut();
});
```

**Markup**:

```
<aside>
    <div class="feature">
        <div class="overlay">
            <a href="">button</a>
        </div><!-- overlay -->                                          
        <div class="text">
            <p>text</p>
        </div><!-- .text-->
        <div class="image">
            <figure>
                <img src="" alt="">
            </figure>
        </div><!-- .image -->
    </div><!-- .feature -->
</aside><!-- aside -->
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/9xRML/5/

**Edit - Final Code**

Thanks @Shomz, and @Afro.

Final code choices were to use tranisitons, and coupled with modernizr  [detection for transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972053/detecting-css-transition-support-with-modernizr), I changed my hidden overlay div to `opacity: 0; *display:none;` and javascript as a fallback:

**CSS**

```
.overlay {
   *display: none;
   opacity: 0; 
   transition: 0.4s all linear;
}
.overlay:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    /*=====================================
    =           Feature overlay           =
    =====================================*/
    if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
        // get aside feature
        var aside_feature = $('aside .feature');

        // on hover, fade it in
        $( aside_feature ).hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.overlay').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
        // on hover out, fade it out
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('.overlay').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: And you want to make those enimovali all at once? Or what exactly do you need?

Comment: What does enimovali mean, sorry?

Comment: Hey, no problem. I think (this) gives that question away as it refers to the element hovered over and not all the divs on the page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With risking of having my answer out of scope here, if you want to really get performance, you should switch to CSS animations. It's totally possible with your example by setting the default opacity of the overlay to 0 (instead of `display: none;`) and making it show up on .feature:hover. The trick is to add the transition property like this:

```
// applies a 4ms transition to any possible property with no easing
transition: all .4s linear;
```

See the whole example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9xRML/6/

See a nice article about the performance difference (CSS vs. JS) here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/ (there are many more, of course)

Comment: I like this idea, I could use specific CSS classes to target browsers that don't support transitions. Or better still, modernizr jQuery: `if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) { // my code };`. Thanks for thinking outside the box, Shomz.

Comment: @SMacFadyen Definitely, it's always nice to have a nice fallback for those old browsers, sorry I forgot to bring it up in the first place. You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved your issue using the same HTML but changing the following:

**JQuery**

```
$('aside .feature').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.overlay').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.overlay').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.feature {
    background: #ccc;
}
.overlay {
    display: none;
}
```

This means the overlay will only display on hover.

Details on `.stop()` [can be found here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/).

**.stop(true, true)**

> We can create a nice fade effect without the common problem of multiple queued animations by adding .stop(true, true) to the chain.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7kCG8/)**

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's helpful and I will use it for the fallback - however, the transition answer will be better suited for anyone who arrives here!